Why do we start HaEl Betaazumot in 3 Regalim
According to Ashkenazim (Nusach Sfard), on regular Shabbat we start Shacharit in Shochen Ad (after Nishmat Kol Chai), whereas in three Regalim we start a few words before: HaEl Betaazumot Uzecha. What is the reason for this? (On Yamim Noraim we start with Hamelech, since we crown Hashem).
